# Funcion de POSTGRESQL para abm

Tags: sql, postgresql

¿Me podrian ayudar con estas lineas de codigo?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION MANTENIMIENTO_MARCA
(P_OPERACION CHAR, P_CODIGO INTEGER, P_DESCRIPCION VARCHAR)
RETURNS void AS
$$
DECLARE
BEGIN
IF (P_OPERACION = 'A') THEN
   INSERT INTO marca(idcodigo, descripcion)
   VALUES(P_CODIGO, P_DESCRIPCION);
END IF;
RETURN;
END; 
$$
LANGUAGE SQL;
```

Al momento de ejecutarlo, me lanza el error de Sintaxis en el IF, que solución le darían ustedes?

Este seria el error que me genera.

```
 ERROR:  error de sintaxis en o cerca de «IF»
 LINE 7: IF (P_OPERACION = 'A') THEN
         ^
 SQL state: 42601
 Character: 141
```

Comment: Por favor añade el mensaje de error que te sale

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tu error radica en la declaración del lenguaje que ha de usar tu función, simplemente sustitúyela por esta línea:

```
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
```

- La declaración va entre comillas
- El lenguaje procedural se llama **`plpgsql`**

Como nota, en la documentación oficial de PostgreSQL se mencionan 4 tipos de lenguajes procedurales soportados por dicho motor:

- plpgsql
- pltcl
- plPerl
- plPython

Como son los únicos soportados, el declarar **`SQL`** no será reconocido por el motor.

**Referencias**

- [lenguaje procedural](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/xplang.html)

Comment: Muchas gracias, ya me funciona